# How do I write another vector as a linear combination without row reducing?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure how I can do this problem without row reduction. I typically just put the 4 vectors in an augmented matrix (with the (1,2,3) being my fourth column in my augmented matrix) and then go to reduced echelon form. How else can I solve this without row reducing?

Here's the answer just for reference; I have no clue how they got that without row reducing:
[image]

Comment: You could invert the matrix

Comment: @J.W.Tanner ok I just inverted it. what would I do with the inverted matrix?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $\begin{bmatrix}3&-1&-1\\1&2&-4\\1&1&7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$.

You could solve for $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ by multiplying both sides by $\begin{bmatrix}3&-1&-1\\1&2&-4\\1&1&7\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$.

Comment: you're genius! thank you! idk how i didnt think of that